# Error starting "XAMPP" stack another instance seems to be running at PID 455

Tags: xampp, localhost

Hi so nothing new has happened on my Mac except maybe an update earlier today and now XAMPP won't start. It comes up with the error "another instance seems to be running at PID 455." I have no idea what this means or how to fix it.

PLEASE HELP

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B5ZD.png)

Answer (score 8):

[See Activity Monitor Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y97my.png)

Open Activity Monitor

Sort by PID

Find the ID of the process to kill, in your case 455

Select the process, click on the X button on the top left of the Activity Monitor window

Answer (score 2):

This is quite old question, but seems many others have unanswered similiar problem.

Kill the PID is not always the solution. When PID is used by a system process, then kill command will be impossible.

Remove the **.bitnami/stackman** folder also danger solution. It will delete all data inside XAMPP, including htdocs folder. Your PHP scripts will be lost.

Simple solution is to delete file **machine.pid** in folder:

> ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/tmp

And then start the XAMPP again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to get the above issue 
you can simply resolve it by removing the stackman folder in your MAC

steps to resolve ::
open your terminal in root folder 
hit the below command

```
rm -rf .bitnami/stackman/
```

all the files will be removed, you can close the xampp and open it, it prompts you as first time installation 
Go ahead..,

Comment: Instead of removing the whole xampp data, all you really need to do is remove the PID from storage, this answer tells how https://stackoverflow.com/a/59875117/11912521

Answer (score 0):

It tells you it is already running xamp. Try to reboot, if that woldnt work open terminal and type `ps aux | grep YOUR_PROCCESS_ID` and kill that process with `kill` command

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's because you have VS Code running the application folder, close VSCode then start xampp then run VSCode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error after I deleted XAMPP-VM and then tried to re-install. Simply rebooting fixed the problem.