# Unable to open XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I use XAMPP to develop my website, my whole site, and in the httdocs folder of XAMPP, there is no backup.

1) When I try to launch XAMPP: I have an error. Here it is in more detail:

another instance seems to be running at PID 526

[image]

I thought about it and I wanted to recover my site first in the htdocs file of XAMPP, but when I go to the source files I can't find this file:

[image]

I'm totally lost, I don't know how to recover my site. Please, how to repair XAMPP or especially how to recover my website and my database?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you don't stop XAMPP application properly, so the old PID is still remains.

To solve the problem, quit XAMPP application, and go to folder:

> ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/tmp

And delete **machine.pid** file inside.

Then start the XAMPP again.